In the windows registry, what values are stored in microphone's (or any hardware's) LastUsedTimeStart key?
For example, checking the microphone usage in Discord, my key Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\microphone\NonPackaged\C:#Users#MyName#AppData#Local#Discord#app-1.0.9152#Discord.exe\LastUsedTimeStart has the value 133665343051866208 and was updated just a few minutes ago (current unix timestamp 1722060933).  That number is way too big to be seconds, and it starts with 13 instead of 17, so it's not related to epoc time.  They're clearly chronological, as they keep incrementing, roughly at a rate of 10 million per second.  What does that number represent, exactly? How can I use that value to answer the question "How long ago did the microphone start?"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime

The value you have encountered is also a date format but in a different format: the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since Jan 1st 1601
Using an online converter that supports this format you get
133665343051866208 = Saturday, 27. July 2024 06:11:45

Wonderful!  Thank you.  Never seen that format, so thanks for educating me.
